# how can i send the data of one route to an other route Mongodb-Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I'm working on MERN application guys and i have question about the backend ! i have 2 models User and admin and i want that the data of the users will be sended to the admin and that admin can manage any user (update, delete, add)

the problem is that i'm working on two different routes (users and admins) and i can't send the data of the users to the admin's data

So this is the schema of the user

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    // Create Schema
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
      username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      birthdate:{
        type: Date
      },
     
      age:{
        type: Number,
     
      pictureID: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "pictures"},
      following: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
      followers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
    });
    module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

AND THIS IS THE SCHEMA OF THE ADMIN

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// Create Schema
const AdminSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  birthdate:{
    type: Date
  },
  age:{
    type: Number,
  },
  pictureID: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "pictures"},
  developers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  testers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
module.exports = Admin = mongoose.model("admins", AdminSchema);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't send the users's data to the admin data"?

Comment: if one developer create a new account i want that would be sended to the admin , I mean it would be pushed in the array "developers" of the admin ! so the admin can get all the developers and testers and manage them !

Answer (score 0):

After you created a new user you can update the developers/testers fields of admin.

```
const admin = await Admin.find({});// find the admin
admin.developers.push(user); //user that you just created
admin.save((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: do i have to write this code in the route admins ? or users ? !

Comment: users routes. Although I'm not sure why you want to save users' reference in admin schema. I don't really see the purpose behind this.

Comment: the admin must have access to all the users(developers and testers) he can get all the users' accounts ,delete their account / he can ban their accounts !

Comment: in the admin routes, you can check if the user who is accessing the route is admin or not. if s/he is the admin then you can find/delete the document pretty easily. Eg
`User.findOneAndRemove({_id: userId})`
`User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId},{$set:{name:'newName'}})`

Comment: well i tried to give the admin the right to delete a user like this `router.route('/delete/:id').delete(function(req, res) {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id, function (err, user){
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.send('Deleted successfully!');
    });
  }); ` it show me deleted successfully but when i get the user i found it , it's still there in the data of the users

Comment: hmm...It should delete the document. What are you getting in `req.body.id` ?

Comment: Well it works for admin to delete and get users but the table developers is empty I put tho code that u gave me in the function register it show me this error message 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' can u help me please

Comment: its because you are sending a response twice to the client. That's why the error 'cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'. please share a screenshot for your function

Comment: I put the screenshot as an answer have a look please

Comment: please edit your answer instead of posting a new answer. There is an error in your code `Admin.find()` line and please do your research before asking any questions. Here's the doc for [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find). It either accepts a callback function or you have to execute it using `admin.exec();` then only you can push developers to it. Also, make sure you handle all the exceptions

Answer (score 0):

[Function register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKk42.png)
this is the function register in the route users ! I add push but it gave an error